# android.util.SuperNotCalledException Crash reported by DeveloperConsole

Tags: android, google-developers-console

The Google Developer Console is reporting a crash for my app:

```
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: 
  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7107)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1330)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4170)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4110)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4068)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1662)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Android-Version

Android 7.0

Gerät
Galaxy S7 (herolte)

Hersteller
    Samsung
RAM (MB)
    4096
Bildschirmgröße
    1440 × 2560
Bildschirmdichte (dpi)
    640
Native Plattform
    armeabi-v7a
OpenGL ES-Version
    3.1
CPU-Marke
    Samsung
CPU-Modell
    Exynos 8890

I cannot find any reference to my source code.
I checked all onPause Methods in my code. All of them do call super.onPause().

So far this carsh has happened only once.

What can I do to avoid this crash ?

Comment: I have the same issue and never had it before, just started with my latest beta two days ago. This in the first version that has overwritten the OnPause and my code has the base called first. I'm guessing its possible an exception is happening after the base is called and so the OnPause call is never returned. However all my code after the base is wrapped in a try\catch, so its also possible it takes to long for the code to complete after the base is called and return from the OnPause. I tried to reproduce this by throwing an exception after the base is called and then by running a blocking in